# Terminal fails with a “Could not create a new process and open a pseudo-tty.” message

Tags: macos, terminal

Yesterday, I upgraded my Mac to Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks), and since then I couldn’t open the “Terminal,” each time I open a session, the following error is shown:

> [Could not create a new process and open a pseudo-tty.]
>
> [Command not found: tmux]

I don’t know what's causing this issue and a fresh restart and killing the relevant processes on activity monitor doesn’t help. Any thoughts?

Comment: The upgrade reset you `/bin` and `/usr/bin` etc., if you installed software there, it's now gone.

Comment: Hi Daniel, so what should be done? Thanx.

Comment: Don't automatically run `tmux` when opening the Terminal, instead, run a shell like `bash`.

Answer (score 6):

It might be a simple and going into Preferences/Startup/Shells open with and select 'Default login shell'.

It is related to where the Shell you are opening, and you can have multiply shells (but that is another thread'

Answer (score 4):

I was getting similar error. So to fix it, within Terminal, I opened

Preferences > General

and set

'Shells open with': to 'Default login shell'.

I then quit and started the terminal app again and the error was gone.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error after upgrading from Lion (10.7) to Mavericks. (10.9)
This fixed it:
Go to Terminal > Preferences > Settings > Shell
and uncheck "Run command".

Answer (score 0):

Do this
terminal>preferences>general>shells open with
then click on "default login shell"

Answer (score 0):

If above answers not fixing the problem

For BigSur OS:
Systempreference > Sharing > Remote Login (check the box) - this will allow port 22 to connect remote hosts via SSH.